# mx:Datagrid not displaying booleans correctly

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer

I am experiencing some rather quirky behaviour with datagrid itemRenderers.
 
First, I create an ArrayCollection as follows:

```
[Bindable]
private var myBooleans:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([false,true]);
```

And afterwards I bind it to a datagrid:

```
<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{myBooleans}" width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
            headerText="Value"
            editorDataField="selected"
            rendererIsEditor="true"
            itemRenderer="mx.controls.CheckBox"
            >
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

When running this, the datagrid only shows a row with the correct itemRenderer if the boolean == true.
For the row where the boolean == false, it will display an empty row.

I would also like to add that wrapping the boolean in a wrapper object will not cut it for my use case since I will receive an ArrayCollection of unwrapped booleans through an RPC call.

Cheers

Comment: Why would you be using a datagrid for a single column?  Why not a list?

Comment: @J_A_X, because the default sorting mechanism would have been a handy asset.
Will have to walk the List path though, and probably scrap the sorting for now.

Comment: Sorting is very easy to accomplish with an Array or ArrayCollection.

Comment: Indeed it is, will be going for a List for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex SDK 3.6; Line 1070-1071 of the DataGridBase is this:

```
    if (item is IDropInListItemRenderer)
        IDropInListItemRenderer(item).listData = data ? rowData : null;
```

Basically, since your data object is false, null values are sent in for listData.  I'm guessing this causes a chain rection which prevents the renderer from rendering.  Thankfully the method, setupColumnItemRenderer, is protected so you can make a go at extending the DataGrid.

I also noticed that the data change event in the renderer never seems to execute for the 'false' items in the dataProvider.  That is unexpected.

It took me ~30 minutes of stepping through code to find this line and I'm not convinced I have the 'answer' 100%.

Comment: I just tried it and you're right! Although, I think at this point it might be easier for him to just go ahead and do a loop on the values returned from the RPC call and set them in a proper object... even though he said he didn't want to do that.

Comment: I noticed that it happens with integers as well. If you create an array of [0,1] and use a plain DataGridColomn, the DataGrid will also display 2 rows, of which one is empty. Of course, it is the row where the data == 0

Comment: @DennisJaamann I'm pretty sure the line would the culprit for Integers too.

Comment: @Jonathan Rowny. As stated, wrapping this is a no go.
I am representing server-stored object states in my DataGrid and will provide a flex editor for a huge object tree. This means that I want to show the data as such and that I do not want to introduce a lot of extra steps to represent object state and then some more to save the modified object state.